# nextSibling issues

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes, siblings

Ok, this has been killing me all night, I mean I've been working on this code for atleast 8 hours now.  What is the problem with this, argggg.

I am trying to update all `<span id="column_[row index number]_[column index number]_[layout position number]">` to increment it by one up until the next `id="row_[row index number]"` `tr element`, The tr elements that it should be searching in has an id of `tr_[row index number]_[column index number]_[layout position number]` but for some god knows what reason, it gives me issues.  It's updating the same `<span>` tag 2x, and this changes it from the desired value to 1 more than it should be... There's only `1 <span>` tag within the `firstChild <td> element` of each of the `<tr> elements`.  I just don't understand why it is setting it 2x for just 1 of them, and it seems that it's random or something.  argggg.

There's only 1 `<span>` element in the `<td id="tdcolumn_[row index number]_[column index number]_[layout position number]>` tag, but for some reason, it is calling the same  tag twice.  It should only call it once. arggg.  I don't understand why??

Here's my code someone please help me here...

```
// Reorder all columns, if any, in the other rows after this 1.
if (aRowId != 0 && lId.indexOf("tr_" + aRowId) == 0 && rowComplete != aRowId)
{
    var tempTr = lTable.childNodes[i].childNodes[p];


    while(tempTr.nodeType == 1 && tempTr.nextSibling != null)
    {
        var tempId = tempTr.getAttribute("id");

        if (!tempId) continue;

        if (tempId.indexOf("row_") == 0)
        {
            // All done this row, set it to completed!
            rowComplete = aRowId;
            break;
        }

        if (tempTr.hasChildNodes)
        {

            var doneChilds = false;

            // grab the id where tdcolumn_{aRowId}.indexOf = 0.
            for (fcTd = 0; fcTd<tempTr.childNodes.length; fcTd++)
            {
                if (tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].nodeName == '#text') continue;

                var tempfcId = tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].getAttribute("id");

                if (!tempfcId) continue;

                if (tempfcId.indexOf("tdcolumn_" + aRowId) != 0) continue;

                // looping through the children in the <td> element here.
                if (tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].hasChildNodes)
                {
                    for (x = tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].childNodes.length-1; x>0; x--)
                    {
                        if (tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].childNodes[x].nodeName == '#text') continue;

                        var tempSpanId = tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].childNodes[x].getAttribute("id");

                        if (!tempSpanId) continue;

                        if (tempSpanId.indexOf("column_") != 0) 
                            continue;

                        // alert(tempSpanId);

                        alert(tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].childNodes[x].nodeName);

                        var tSpanId = new Array();
                        tSpanId = tempSpanId.split("_");

                        if (currColumnId == 0)
                        {
                            currColumnId = parseInt(tSpanId[1]);
                            var incCol = currColumnId;  
                        }

                        incCol++;

                        // alert("currColumnId = " + currColumnId + "\n\ntSpanId[1] = " + tSpanId[1] + "\n\nincCol = " + incCol);

                        // Set the new Id's and Text, after which we can exit the for loop.
                        tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].childNodes[x].setAttribute("id", "column_" + incCol);
                        tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].childNodes[x].setAttribute("class", "dp_edit_column");
                        tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].childNodes[x].innerHTML = oColumnText + " " + incCol;
                        // tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].setAttribute("id", "tdcolumn_" + aRowId + "_" + (parseInt(tSpanId[1])+1) + "_" + tSpanId[3]);

                        doneChilds = true;

                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                    continue;

                if (doneChilds == true)
                    continue;
            }
        }
        else
            continue;

        tempTr = tempTr.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

Please help me, Thank You :)

Comment: You might want to tag this with the appropriate language tag (Javascript ?).

Comment: @SoLoGHoST: This looks like a perfect opportunity to move to a JavaScript framework. DOM manipulation at this complexity level gets a lot easier and more portable this way. Also - have you tried setting a breakpoint in the developer tools of your browser and stepping through the code line by line? Should be pretty easy to find out what's wrong with a debugger...

Comment: I get no errors, how do I setup a breakpoint?  And how does that help.  I've been using alerts to give me variable information...lol.  Sorry if that sounds like a dumb question :(

Comment: Bytheway, I've used alert boxes to halt it a bit when changing the innerHTML of each <span> tag, but I see that it sets it to the right value "Column 6", but than changes the same <span> innerHTML to say "Column 7", so I know it is working, and I know that it is setting the same element twice, which I don't want it to do... argg.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm setting the id attribute forwards instead of backwards??  Since I'm splitting it up using the `id="column_[some number]"`

Comment: You don't need an error do go into debug mode. Open developer tools, set a breakpoint, reload your page. If you don't know how to do this, you probably should spend a few minutes on learning how. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak, ha, ha, no. JavaScript libraries are the worst for one who is learning. http://azabani.com/51

Comment: @Delan: You link to your own blog post for proof? ;) I think time is better spent learning the library than learning the vendor-specific DOM peculiarities and working around the same oddities time and time again. JS libraries are JS themselves, they do not keep you from learning the language, quite to the contrary. JavaScript is a programming language, it is *not the same as DOM manipulation*. And if you have a lot of the latter, why not take advantage of some help?

Comment: I really need an example page to walk through your code, it's not totally clear to me what the intended behaviour is.

Comment: The code looks way too complicated and the description is a little confusing. What are `column_N`, `row_N`, `tr_N_N_N`, and `tdcolumn_N_N_N` and how are they related. Post a sample of the html structure to make it simpler.

Comment: Sorry bout that, here's the structure:  all id suffixes are like this, cept for the `id="row_[row index number]"`, `[row index number]_[column index number]_[layout position number]`  I just recently changed the `id="column_"` to the same thing so that it has the same suffix.  The layout position number is coming directly from the database (auto-incremented column that starts at 1).  So when new columns are created, it makes the `layout position number` = to `0` for that column.  Well hopefully this helps you to understand, also updated the question with this info.

Comment: The idea is to do all of the work in Javascript, and than when they submit the form, it creates the hidden input elements and posts it via PHP and does the actual work in the database table set aside for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I don't think I can solve your problem without the relevant HTML parts, I see at least one error in your code:

```
if (doneChilds = true)
```

This always evaluates to `true`. It should read:

```
if (doneChilds)
```

BTW, you don't need `getAttribute` here:

```
var tempfcId = tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].getAttribute("id");
```

Just use:

```
var tempfcId = tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].id;
```

Never set a class name using `setAttribute`, like here:

```
tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].childNodes[x].setAttribute("class", "dp_edit_column");
```

Use:

```
tempTr.childNodes[fcTd].childNodes[x].className = "dp_edit_column";
```

(the same is true for the line above that one, setting the `id` of an element).

Comment: Hello Marcel Korpel, if you'd like I can send you the link and access to the Admin Part of the forum, since you would need these in order to see the actual example.  Because it's in the Administration part of the forum.  It would be too much work to take it out of there, but I suppose it's possible...  Let me know if you can still help, k?  I really do appreciate this!!! :)